# WSO2IS 5.10.0. lastLoginTime update in Custom Local Authenticator

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I wrote my custom local authenticator. When I used it the lastLoginTime doesn't update. Logging with basic authenticator is ok.

Which extension responsible update lastLoginTime? What I need to do in my authenticator to update lastLoginTime? Thanks!

Update:
I made custom authenticator for using with user credentials that authenticator gets from XML Signature. The authenticator gets XML, verify signature, extract special_user_id and then checks this id in UserStroe in custom claim. If user with this claim value exists then authentificator gets user_name from User Store and finishes processAuthenticationResponse() with success.

In short

```
processAuthenticationResponse() {

...

String[] logins = userStoreManager.getUserList("http://wso2.org/claims/special_user_id", specialUserIdValue, "default");

context.setSubject(AuthenticatedUser.createLocalAuthenticatedUserFromSubjectIdentifier(logins[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IS-5.10.0, the last login time is updated only if the idle user suspension feature https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/user-account-suspension/ is enabled.

IS-5.10.0 contains the identity-governance component version 1.4.1. Here is the code lines related to updating the last login time https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/57e510a61dc9042b55ffa0cbdceb13f508519f3a/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.account.suspension.notification.task/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/account/suspension/notification/task/handler/AccountSuspensionNotificationHandler.java#L84-L85

It's irrespective whether you use the basic authenticator / a custom authenticator. If you have enabled idle user account suspension feature,at every `POST_AUTHENTICATION` event this AccountSuspensionNotificationHandler's handleEvent should be invoked and update the last login time.

NOTE: In IS-5.11.0, the last login time value update logic is changed. It can be updated irrespective of idle user account suspension feature. Check https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/4515

---

Update:

- Here is the reason for not triggering `POST_AUTHENTICATION` event when using the custom authenticator.
- If you use the basic authenticator, user is authenticated from the  IS userstore connecting through the userstore manager.

After the authentication happens in userstore https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/56d068221ab46e205d5b7188e2bc55134bfc08a9/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java#L1757, the configured listeners' `doPostAuthenticate` method is invoked.
The `POST_AUTHENTICATION` event is triggered from `IdentityMgtEventListener`'s , `doPostAuthenticate` method https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/57e510a61dc9042b55ffa0cbdceb13f508519f3a/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/governance/listener/IdentityMgtEventListener.java#L122-L127

- Since the above flow doesn't get executed when you use a custom authenticator which doesn't authenticate the user from WSO2 IS userstore,  `POST_AUTHENTICATION` event is not triggered.

Possible options to follow to trigger `POST_AUTHENTICATION` event from the custom authenticator.

1. Override the `public AuthenticatorFlowStatus process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationContext context) throws AuthenticationFailedException, LogoutFailedException {` method to user custom authenticator with same logic in the `AbstractApplicationAuthenticator` method. Then add

```
fireEvent(context, IdentityEventConstants.Event.POST_AUTHENTICATION, true);
```

before

```
return AuthenticatorFlowStatus.SUCCESS_COMPLETED;
```

similar to https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/527dba704487431b95c34461656cdb7496a0f0cc/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/AbstractLocalApplicationAuthenticator.java#L80-L81

2. Extend your custom authenticator from `AbstractLocalApplicationAuthenticator` instead of `AbstractApplicationAuthenticator`. Note that there are differences in the authentication process method in those two classes.

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, the user suspension feature is enabled. When I logged in with user and password the last login time is updated. It's all works.
But with custom authenticator POST_AUTHENTICATION event doesn't triggered. How to trigger POST_AUTHENTICATION event?

Comment: What is the guide you followed to write the custom authenticator? Is it a custom local authenticator or a federated authenticator? Which abstract authenticator did you extend ?

Comment: This guide: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/federation/write-a-custom-local-authenticator/

extends AbstractApplicationAuthenticator implements LocalApplicationAuthenticator

Method processAuthenticationResponse completed without errors.

I dont use userStoreManager.authenticate

Comment: Check the "update" section of the posted answer to see the reason for not triggering POST_AUTHENTICATION event in your case, and a possible solution

Comment: However, I have a doubt about managing users in your setup. As per the comments you are not authenticating the users via userstore manager, but you maintain the users in the userstore for user listing/ profile management. What is the reason for not using the userStoreManager.authenticate?

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it's than I need.
I made custom authentificator for using with user credentials that authentificator gets from XML Signature. The authentificator gets XML, verify signature, extract special_user_id and then checks this id in UserStroe in custom claim. If user with this claim value exists then authentificator gets user_name from User Store and finishes processAuthenticationResponse() with success.

Comment: Added update to question.