# How to set last login time claim in WSO2 IS 5.11

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to set lastLoginTime/lastLogonTime claim for the user during login. I can see possibilities to create custom authenticator or adaptive authentication script, but Im wondering if its possible to do automatically. I found this issue on WSO2IS github: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/4515 where it was decoupled from idle account suspension, however I don't know how to configure it to make it work. How it should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following config to `<wso2is-home>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file to enable the identityUserMetadataMgtHandler event handler.

```
[identity_mgt.events.schemes.identityUserMetadataMgtHandler.properties]
enable=true
```

That event handler updates the last logon time of the users when they log into applications. It will update the login timestamp in http://wso2.org/claims/identity/lastLogonTime claim.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75163711/10055162,
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74958472/10055162

Comment: Thank you! Is there a possibility to turn it on only for one tenant? Enabling it in deployment.toml will cause that every user will get this claim updated, right?

Comment: There is no tenant-wise config to enable this handler only in specific tenants. As you said by enabling it via the deployment.toml will applicable for every tenant in the IS server.

Comment: Ok, so setting it for one tenant its doable only via adaptive authentication script or custom 
authenticator?

Comment: You can use the account suspension feature which can be enabled tenant wise to keep track of last login time. But need to make sure to set a large value for number for "Account lock after" configuration. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/user-account-suspension/